# Connect to MongoDB database using mongoose behind a proxy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, proxy, mongoose, mlab

I am using mongoose to connect to my database in mongolab in my server.js file :

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://MyUsername:MyPassword@ds089702.mongolab.com:89702/todo');
```

When i launch my server with `node server.js` command, i see this error in my terminal

> failed to connect to [ds089702.mongolab.com:89702]

I am very sure that is just a corporate proxy problem, so I'm wondering how can I connect to my database over the corporate proxy using mongoose ?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Hello @LeRoy Sadly, No :/

Comment: No solution yet ??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and figured out a solution that worked for me.

Example mongodb URI:

mongodb://:@ds123456.mlab.com:37409/dbName

1. Use a proxy client (e.g. [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/)).
2. Create a HTTPS proxy through port 8080 using your corporate proxy as the address.

[image]

3. Create a rule for mlab using your URI's port as the target port, which uses the HTTPS proxy you created above as its action.

[image]

4. Prioritize your mlab rule high in the rules list.

[image]

Comment: any free version for mac?

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh proxifier has a free trial period. You might be able to find a free alternative.