# Using mongoose and mlab behind a proxy

Tags: mongoose, proxy, mlab

Can't connect to my mlab database if I'm behind a proxy.

Any idea how to achieve this? I've already googled and found no answer...

Here is my connection:

```
mongoose.connect(config.db.URI);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function(){
    throw new Error('unable to connect to database at ' + config.db.URI);
});
```

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483140/connect-to-mongodb-database-using-mongoose-behind-a-proxy) but it doesn't look like that one's been answered yet either.  Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: No I ended up installing a local mongo and imported my data from mlab

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: Please consider my proxy client solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699452/5464788) that worked for me.

Comment: @davejlin  did you have to buy Proxifier?