# Connect to MongoDB using mongoose with proxy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, proxy, firewall

**Goal** : Connect to a public facing mongodb instance in my local development environment, which is connected to my corporate network.

**Background** : There is a proxy available for bypassing this corporate firewall. I am developing a Next JS application with mongo as the backend.

**Ask** : How do I use this proxy to connect to the mongo instance in my node js application?

```
 const db = await mongoose
      .connect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGO_URI, {
        dbName: "cusum",
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.reason));
```

This is how I connect to my mongo db instance using `mongoose`, in my node js application.  It works when not connected to my corporate network, but times out when connected to my corporate network.

I was able to connect to the instance using [Studio 3T with its built in proxy support](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/connect-to-mongodb/), however this is just a GUI client for mongo db.

**Attempts**

I have attempted to use the [`global-tunnel`](https://github.com/np-maintain/global-tunnel) package to route all http connections to the proxy but it didn't work.

```
globalTunnel.initialize({
  host: "proxy-xx.xxx.com",
  port: 8080,
  protocol: "http:",
  connect: "both",
});
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link can help on a corporate proxy issue

[Connect to MongoDB database using mongoose behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483140/connect-to-mongodb-database-using-mongoose-behind-a-proxy)

Also, you can look into Nginx as a proxy, depending on your company configuration, though I see you're working wit Nextjs, most of it will depend on the configuration used at your company